# Google app engine did not run one of the tasks in the push queue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have a B2 machine running tasks from the default push queue. I added 4 tasks to the queue, and task2 didnt run, no logs about it appear in the admin console, and i dont see any failures. task1, task3, and task4 successfuly finished.

the way i adding the tasks (simply one after the other):

```
 taskqueue.add(url='/run_task', params={'param1' : param1_value})
```

I looked but cant find any restrictions about the max concurant tasks for a bakend (i think once it was about 10), also I would expect in any kind of internal failure a future retry no?

any idea?

Comment: This happened to me too , in my case the issue was that no instance was available to serve the request.

Comment: yeah thats what i thoght, but isnt it a bit wierd it wouln't retry to run it later? this is a huge problem in terms of consistansy...

Comment: yes thats weird, but it can be handled either by increasing the number of instances in module or by setting a cronjob (cronjob might not be suitable in your case i guess)

Comment: yeah, but if google app engine skips tasks, that can happen anyway down the line (i dont know how many instances i need until i see the throughput). cronjob is indeed not a suitable solution in my case. thanks for the response.